# Need guidance in understanding rkhunter results

Tags: linux, rootkit

Today, I performed a system wide scan for rootkits using the rkhunter --check command. All results were ok, with the exception of a warning:

```
[10:14:30] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/unhide.rb' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/unhide.rb: Ruby script, ASCII text
```

The final results were:

```
[10:15:53] System checks summary
[10:15:53] =====================
[10:15:53]
[10:15:53] File properties checks...
[10:15:53] Files checked: 130
[10:15:53] Suspect files: 1
[10:15:53]
[10:15:53] Rootkit checks...
[10:15:53] Rootkits checked : 242
[10:15:53] Possible rootkits: 0
[10:15:53]
[10:15:53] Applications checks...
[10:15:53] All checks skipped
[10:15:53]
[10:15:53] The system checks took: 1 minute and 43 seconds
[10:15:53]
[10:15:53] Info: End date is Sat Mar 16 10:15:53 IST 2013
```

Since I'm a newbie here, I don't get the warning. Should I be worried about that or is it just an anomaly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is very common, and has been reported as a bug:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3601300&group_id=155034&atid=794187

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=607224

The warning is nothing to worry about.